# одна и та же Ячейка имеет разные размеры в разных tableView. как исправить?

Tags: swift

Имеет переиспользуемая ячейка таблицы с фото и именем. В одном табличном представлении эта ячейка отображатеся корректно. При переходе на другую таблицу эта же ячейка выглядит шире чем на предыдущей таблице. Соответственно закругления и тени для ячейки выглядят не так как на первой таблице изза того что размер изображения стал больше.
Я облазил весь сториборд, и путем сравнения каждого эелемента двух разных viewControllerов искал какие то отличия в размерах там, ничего не нашел.

код ячейки

```
import UIKit

class FriendsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var friendsCellImage: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet var backView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var friendsCellName: UILabel?

func setup() {
    friendsCellImage?.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    friendsCellImage?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    friendsCellImage?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    backView.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    backView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
  
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setup()
}
```

код первого контроллера где изображение имеет нужный формат.

```
import UIKit

class FriendsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var friendsTableView: UITableView!
//MARK: - Properties
    // indentifier
    private let cellID = "FriendsTableViewCell"
    //Friends Array
    var friends = [User(userName: "Moni", userImage: UIImage(named: "2_1")),
                  User(userName: "Alex", userImage: UIImage(named: "1_2")),
                  User(userName: "Mama", userImage: UIImage(named: "1_3")),
                  User(userName: "Oma", userImage: UIImage(named: "4"))]


@IBAction func goBackFromAnotherScreen(with segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    guard let anotherVC = segue.source as? AnotherFriendsViewController, let indexPath = anotherVC.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
    
    let newUser = anotherVC.friends[indexPath.row]
    
    guard !friends.contains(where: { User ->Bool in
        User.userName == newUser.userName 
        
    }) else { return }
        
    
    friends.append(newUser)
    friendsTableView.reloadData()
    }
 
}
extension FriendsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friends.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: 
indexPath) as? FriendsTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("{ Message: Error in dequeue FriendsTableViewCell }")
    }
    cell.friendsCellName?.text = friends[indexPath.row].userName
    cell.friendsCellImage?.image = friends[indexPath.row].userImage
    
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
 CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

а вот код второго контроллера где изображение растягивается в ширь, не на много, но закругления картинки уже невозможно.

```
import UIKit

class AnotherFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - OUTLETS
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

//MARK: - PROPERTIES
let reuseId = "AnotherFriends"
var friends = [User(userName: "Jack", userImage: UIImage(named: "2_1")),
              User(userName: "Bob", userImage: UIImage(named: "1_2")),
              User(userName: "Adam", userImage: UIImage(named: "1_3")),
              User(userName: "Kate", userImage: UIImage(named: "3")),
              User(userName: "Ahmed", userImage: UIImage(named: "4"))]

 }

 extension AnotherFriendsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return friends.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
 UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseId, for: 
 indexPath) as? FriendsTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("{ Message: Error in dequeue FriendsTableViewCell }")
    }
    cell.friendsCellName?.text = friends[indexPath.row].userName
    cell.friendsCellImage?.image = friends[indexPath.row].userImage
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

как сделать так чтобы ячейка выглядела во всех такблицах   одинаково?

Comment: По коду с размерами ячеек проблем нет, надо смотреть сториборды. Выложите эту часть проекта на гитхаб и добавьте ссылку, посмотрим.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за внимание к моему вопросу

https://github.com/Woodshox/VK_Client

Comment: Посмотрите в сториборде, у вас Friends Cell Image и Group Cell Image имеют разные приоритеты у констрейнта width (1000 и 999), поэтому по разному выглядят.

Comment: Ох спасибо Вам большое! Даже и подумать не мог, что констрейнты так могут "подпортить" жизнь xD)

Comment: @OlegSoloviev что то не могу отметить ваш ответ как "Правильный" в любом случае спасибо

Comment: А это комментарий, его не отметить :) Пожалуйста.